# Segmentation fault in neural network

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, neural-network, fault

I have been writing a code for a neural network using back propagation algorithm and for propagating inputs I have written the following code,but just for two inputs,its displaying segmentation fault.Is there any wrong withe code.I wan not able to figure it out....

```
void propagateInput(int cur,int next)
{
    cout<<"propagating input"<<cur<<"  "<<next<<endl;   
    cout<<"Number of nerons : "<<neuronsInLayer[cur]<<"  "<<neuronsInLayer[next]<<endl;
    for(int i = 0;i < neuronsInLayer[next];i++)
    {
        neuron[next][i].output = 0;
        for(int j = 0;j < neuronsInLayer[cur];j++)
        {
            cout<<neuron[cur][j].output<<" ";
            cout<<neuron[next][i].weight[j]<<"\n";
            neuron[next][i].output += neuron[next][i].weight[j] * neuron[cur][j].output;
        }
        cout<<"out["<<i<<"] = "<<neuron[next][i].output<<endl;
    }
    cout<<"completed propagating input.\n";
}
```

Comment: Please add details on the allocation of any arrays you iterate over. Also tell what operation specifically caused the segmentation fault. Did you use a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0;i < neuronsInLayer[next];i++)...
```

neuronsInLayer[next] is a pointer. perhaps if i knew the type of neuronsInLayer i could assist you more.

Comment: @soma sekhar - Is `neuronsInLayer` pointing to valid memory locations? Does it have an index where it can point to `next` ?

Comment: yes,it has..I have checked it by printing the value in neuronsInLayer[next] and verified if it is as per required...

Answer (score 0):

That is not anywhere near enough information to debug your code. No info about line numbers or how the structures are laid out in memory or which ones are valid, etc.

So let me tell you how you can find this yourself. If you're using a Unix/Mac then use the GDB debugger on your executable, a.out:

```
$ gdb a.out
> run
*segfault*
> where
```

Visual Studio has a great debugger as well, just run it in Debug mode and it'll tell you where the segfault is and let you inspect memory.